# Button get cover by background effect using CSS on React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

I have been trying to create a simple background effect with CSS but I realize it could cover up all content including the button, so I won't be able to click on it, how could I put the effect at the back of the page, please?

Here are my codes:

https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-carlos-z9nikn?file=/src/App.js:23-598

Edit: I have forgotten to add a background color, I have tried z-index:-999 it will go behind the background color instead, is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`circles` is covering all contents. 
So adding -9999 to the z-index of the `circles` class will solve it.

```css
.circles {
 z-index: -9999;
 background-color: black;
 ... 
}
```

The code is below: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-blackburn-shzjoe?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: Sorry i have forgotten to add background color (i have put it back on now), it wouldn't work if I added the background back in

Comment: @tomtom I fix the code with background color. Can you check the code? And is it okay to move background color to `.circles`?

Comment: i have never thought it would be the background in the .circle, thanks alot of your help, i have got it working now!